# ArrayList object is returing one row on ListView in java android

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview, arraylist

I am trying to add Objects from `MySQL` database on `ArrayList` Object but result gives me only one row 
i am using custom adapter on my `ListView`, i think i could use loop multiple objects to `ArrayList` object but i failed , please help me,

my code :

```
String driver_fullname = json.getString("driver_fullname");
String driver_phonenumber = json.getString("driver_phonenumber");
String plate_no = json.getString("plate_no");
String parking_name = json.getString("parking_name");

List<PaymentTiming_Items> getAllDiverDetails = new ArrayList<PaymentTiming_Items>();
PaymentTiming_Items timingItems = new PaymentTiming_Items();
timingItems.setPlateNo(plate_no);
timingItems.setParkingName(parking_name);
timingItems.setDriverFullName(driver_fullname);
getAllDiverDetails.add(timingItems); // store all drivers' info to
}

if (getAllDiverDetails.size() !=0) {
userList =  new ArrayList<>   (getAllDiverDetails);
listAdapter = new PaymentTiming_ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: can you add custom layout xml.. check whether its height is "match prent". if it it match_parent change it to wrap_content

Comment: @Tomin B  Custom layout is in custom adapter ,the problem i think is not Layout

Comment: add how you load multiple data.? there is no loop in code.

Comment: @Mohamed, No error i am getting, the problem is that my json produces many rows but i get only one row on ListView through ArrayList

Comment: am update my comment - add code for loading mutiple data.

Comment: @Mohamed Mohaideen AH , There is not loop ofcourse i was asking myself the way i can use it on ArrayList objects dynamically

Comment: you can read all data from json response then load into array list. Above code add only one data to arraylist.

Comment: @AlexisMUGWANEZA if my answer worked, can you please accept it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are creating an ArrayList everytime you parse an object. If I understand correctly, your code should be something like that:

```
// ArrayList will be created only once for a json response.
    List<PaymentTiming_Items> getAllDiverDetails = new ArrayList<PaymentTiming_Items>();

  //Now parse add all elements in json response and add to list.
        for(all items in your jsonResponse List ) {    
            //Parse fields from json object
            String driver_fullname = json.getString("driver_fullname");
            String driver_phonenumber = json.getString("driver_phonenumber");
            String plate_no = json.getString("plate_no");
            String parking_name = json.getString("parking_name");

            //create object
            PaymentTiming_Items timingItems = new PaymentTiming_Items();
            timingItems.setPlateNo(plate_no);
            timingItems.setParkingName(parking_name);
            timingItems.setDriverFullName(driver_fullname);
            getAllDiverDetails.add(timingItems); // store all drivers' info to
        }

        //Now list will have all the items, Add this list to adapter.   
            if (getAllDiverDetails.size() !=0) {
            userList =  new ArrayList<>(getAllDiverDetails);
            listAdapter = new PaymentTiming_ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
            myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you , you're right i was  parsing an object everytime

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Your Server gives a result in `JSONArray` say **response** as a String Try the following

```
List<PaymentTiming_Items> getAllDiverDetails = new ArrayList<PaymentTiming_Items>();


        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
        int size = jsonArray.length();
        if (size > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String driver_fullname = json.getString("driver_fullname");
                String driver_phonenumber = json.getString("driver_phonenumber");
                String plate_no = json.getString("plate_no");
                String parking_name = json.getString("parking_name");


                PaymentTiming_Items timingItems = new PaymentTiming_Items();
                timingItems.setPlateNo(plate_no);
                timingItems.setParkingName(parking_name);
                timingItems.setDriverFullName(driver_fullname);
                getAllDiverDetails.add(timingItems); // store all drivers' info to
            }
        }

if (getAllDiverDetails.size() !=0) {
userList =  new ArrayList<>   (getAllDiverDetails);
listAdapter = new PaymentTiming_ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), userList);
myList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `JSONArray` for getting list of items from `JSON`. And then populate your `ArrayList` with them and pass to your adapter.